# Use __attribute__((section()) with an offset in C without modifying linker script

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

Is it possible to use Use  __ attribute __((section with an offset to a linker section so that a linker script doesn't have to be modified (there is a good reason we have for this - automated code generation).

Eg I'd like to do the following:

```
U32 variable __attribute__((section (".VARIABLE" + 0x32)));
```

Linker script has the following:

```
SECTIONS
{
    /* magic ram location
  .VARIABLE 0x60020000 : {KEEP(*(.VARIABLE))}
}
```

I would like to have the address of variable to be linked at 0x60020032. Is there anyway to do this in the C file without modifying the linker script? I know I could effectively make a pointer and add an offset but I want to declare it directly in the C file if possible.

Comment: `there is a good reason we have for this - automated code generation` I do not understand, what is the reason for this? How does automated code generation _force_ you to use an offset with attribute section?  Just put a structure inside the section with variable of type `U32` at offset 0x32 from the start of the struct.

Comment: It is extremely bad idea.